# How to perform distributed testing in JMeter for different tenants with multiple app servers?

Tags: java, ant, jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-testing

I have to do performance testing on 3 web/app servers which are accessed by 5 different tenants(URLs). The operations are same in all the tenants with JDBC authentication.

I have multiple JMX files, take one for example ie. JMX for Signin and Signout functions.

**Note**:** Here all the JMX are recorded from one single tenant.

**Note**:** 1 DB for 1 tenant, so all the tenants have different logins.

**What I need to do is:** Execute the JMX for all the tenants in Parallel. Signin & Signout should be performed in all the tenants at the same time.

So far, I have tried distributed testing and failed to get on that. Currently working with ANT and still I dont have clear idea on how to achieve parallel JMX execution in different tenants.

Please suggest me any solution.Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Bala.

Comment: CSV with 3 servers x 5 tenants/usernames/passwords = 15 lines in CSV. Each thread will pick up one configuration, with 15 or more threads they all run on parallel. If you need separate stats, give samplers dynamic names based on config from CSV. If tests are the same, that should work. If not, please give an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The only guaranteed option to have certain requests running at exactly the same moment is merging your multiple JMX files into single test plan using i.e. [Include Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) or Module Controllers and using [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

---

If you're just looking for a way to execute multiple JMX files in parallel the easiest option would be going for [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool. Taurus acts like a wrapper for JMeter

The relevant YAML configuration file would be something like:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    script: Signin.jmx
- scenario: 
    script: Signout.jmx
```

More information: [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests)